# Js - Move 500 word to another div in Article post

Tags: jquery

I have one article with 1000s word. But i want js will count 500 words it'll add this to div1. 500 words left will add to div2.

How to do it? Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your article into Array of strings by using `split(' ')` function which will create an array of 1000 words.

Then by using `.splice(0,500)` you can get the 1st 500 words and the you can join them using `.join(' ')` function which will give you the string of 1st 500 words and then you can append the string to the Div.

Now by using splice function array will now only contains the remaining 500 words so you can directly join the remaining words and append to the second div.

Below is the working snippet with example of 20 words which you can convert for 1000 words.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var str="word1 word2 word3 word4 word5 word6 word7 word8 word9 word10 word11 word12 word13 word14 word15 word16 word17 word18 word19 word20"
  var strArray = str.split(' ');
  $('#firstDiv').text(strArray.splice(0,10).join(' '));
  $('#secondDiv').text(strArray.join(' '));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='firstDiv'>

</div>
<div id='secondDiv'  style="margin-top :10px;;" >

</div>
```